# dart:uri in generated Dart html pages does not run

Tags: dart

With the latest version of dart (editor 24275) I keep getting an error re: dart:uri

This is placed in my built html:

`import "dart:isolate" as FB;import "dart:uri" as MH;import "dart:json" as ............`

Dart VM version: 0.5.20.4_r24275 (Fri Jun 21 05:02:35 2013) on "macos_ia32"

dart:uri is now in dart:core I recall.. but my html keeps getting built with this in it and so doesn't run in Chromium with the Dart VM

I've removed the out folder and rebuilt, does not resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you definitely removed all instances of `import "dart:uri"` from your code, whether they are stand alone Dart scripts or scripts embedded in HTML templates/components etc?

It's always good to run "Reanalyze Sources" too.

Comment: Ran "reanalyze..."
did..
`Doug-Fils-MacBook-Pro:src dfils$ find  . -name "*.dart" -exec grep -il dart:ui {} \; `
Doug-Fils-MacBook-Pro:src dfils$ find  . -name "*.html" -exec grep -il dart:ui {} \;

also deleted everything from web/out and deploy directories..

re-build and run and dart:ui is placed back into the generated HTML files...

is there something else I can delete..  my pub archive in my dot files?

Comment: @DouglasFils Both your finds are looking for "dart:ui" instead of "dart:uri", is that a typo here or in what you actually ran?

Comment: sadly, no I did it that way and when I did it right I found the issues hidden in my web components HTML files that get included.    Sorry for the wild goose chase.

Comment: @DouglasFils At least we finally found the problem, that's a good result!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to run pub update.